# Why can't the search function Cannot be added?

Tags: android, flutter, list, dart, search

I am New to Flutter And Dart. 
Hope some one help me with this

**I made a screen with this code below**

```
// ignore_for_file: use_build_context_synchronously, library_private_types_in_public_api

import 'package:loading_animation_widget/loading_animation_widget.dart';

import '../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'detailspage.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:quickalert/quickalert.dart';

class UdemyScreen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const UdemyScreen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UdemyScreen1State createState() => _UdemyScreen1State();
}

class _UdemyScreen1State extends State<UdemyScreen1> {
  MaterialColor materialColor = const MaterialColor(0xFF212967, {
    50: Color(0xFFF4F5F8),
    100: Color(0xFFE9EAF0),
    200: Color(0xFFC8CAD9),
    300: Color(0xFFA4A8C1),
    400: Color(0xFF646A95),
    500: Color(0xFF212967),
    600: Color(0xFF1E255C),
    700: Color(0xFF14193E),
    800: Color(0xFF0F132F),
    900: Color(0xFF0A0C1E),
  });
  bool _isloading = true;
  List<Widget> childre = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    //Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4), );
    dotask();
    super.initState();
  }

  void dotask() async {
    const storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    String? token = await storage.read(key: 'token');
    final response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse('https://backend.s4tyendra.eu.org/udemy?token=$token'));
    //QuickAlert.show(context: context, type: QuickAlertType.info);
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      QuickAlert.show(
          context: context,
          type: QuickAlertType.error,
          title: 'Error',
          text: 'Server Error Or Cannot connect');
    } else {
      final List<dynamic> list = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
      for (var element in list) {
        final id = element['course']['id'];
        String title = element['course']['title'];
        childre.add(Hero(
          tag: id,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(18, 18, 18, 18),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => DeailspageWidget(
                            title: title,
                            id: id,
                          )),
                );
              },
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  title,
                  style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).title3,
                ),
                subtitle: Text(
                  id,
                  style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).subtitle2,
                ),
                trailing: Column(
                  children: [
                    FaIcon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.circleRight,
                      color: materialColor.shade900,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                tileColor: const Color.fromARGB(183, 255, 255, 255),
                dense: true,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
      }
      setState(() {
        _isloading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: materialColor.shade700,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: _isloading
            ? Center(
                child: LoadingAnimationWidget.fourRotatingDots(
                    color: Colors.green, size: 60),
              )
            : GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: childre,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The token is unique user token
**Response from url is**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4284484",
                "title": "The Complete Dart Learning Guide [2022 Edition]"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4447514",
                "title": "Practical Next.js & React - Build a real WebApp with Next.js"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4893248",
                "title": "Object Detection on Custom Dataset With Keras Using Python"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3014476",
                "title": "The Ethical  Hacking Bootcamp"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4309598",
                "title": "Master Data Analysis with Pandas"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3014498",
                "title": "Anonymity Guide For Ethical Hackers"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3785848",
                "title": "Learn Mobile Photography Techniques For Incredible Photos"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3201902",
                "title": "Kali Linux Basics Course For Cyber Security"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4524086",
                "title": "Learn Web Application Security For Beginners- OWASP Top 10"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2051729",
                "title": "SEO Training- Complete SEO Course & SEO Copywriting MASTERY"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3658756",
                "title": "Hands-On React. Build advanced React JS Frontend with expert"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4390890",
                "title": "Python for Deep Learning- Build Neural Networks in Python"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4774346",
                "title": "React.JS- The Complete Course for Beginners"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4818998",
                "title": "Three.js - The Complete Beginner to Advanced Course"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2955276",
                "title": "Deep Web- The complete Introduction to the hidden web"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4782576",
                "title": "Certified MongoDB Developer & Database Administrator Pack"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "1490124",
                "title": "Complete Wordpress Website Developer Course"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2503534",
                "title": "Complete Machine Learning with R Studio - ML for 2022"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4757506",
                "title": "Cyber Security- Common Attacks"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3726582",
                "title": "Complete JAVASCRIPT with HTML5,CSS3 from zero to Expert-2022"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4907934",
                "title": "Modern GUI Development - Python (Software Development)"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3432584",
                "title": "Sentiment Analysis with NLP using Python and Flask"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4704782",
                "title": "LookML A-Z- Google Looker for Developers"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2663858",
                "title": "Google Analytics For Beginners"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4260384",
                "title": "Insight to Post Pandemic- Importance of Lean Six Sigma"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4189430",
                "title": "Digital Marketing Course for Fitness Professionals (2022)"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4147070",
                "title": "Become a Pro WordPress Freelancer & Get Web Design Clients"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3202534",
                "title": "Google BigQuery & PostgreSQL - Big Query for Data Analysis"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4202336",
                "title": "Object Oriented Programming in C++  &  Interview Preparation"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4897384",
                "title": "Full Stack Web Developer"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4678800",
                "title": "Ethical Hacking- Linux Privilege Escalation"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4719804",
                "title": "Debugging Bootcamp - Software techniques beyond windbg,gdb"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3407178",
                "title": "Python And Flask Framework Complete Course"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4898058",
                "title": "2022-Basics of SQL using PostgreSQL"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4663402",
                "title": "CheckPoint Management Server R81 HA Configuration"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "1592856",
                "title": "jQuery for Absolute Beginners - From Beginning to Advanced"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4533524",
                "title": "Batch Script Programming Crash Course (CMD)"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3271350",
                "title": "CheckPoint Firewall Administration R80"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3776992",
                "title": "CheckPoint-NGFW Security - Basic Introduction"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4522782",
                "title": "Blogging & Content Writing Course - Start A Profitable Blog"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4870254",
                "title": "Google Search Essential Class || GET CERTIFICATE ||"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2411008",
                "title": "HTML, CSS, & JavaScript - Certification Course for Beginners"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2410960",
                "title": "JavaScript & jQuery - Certification Course for Beginners"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2410966",
                "title": "HTML, JavaScript, & Bootstrap - Certification Course"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2410976",
                "title": "NGINX, Apache, SSL Encryption - Certification Course"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2444060",
                "title": "How the Internet Works & the Web Development Process"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2444066",
                "title": "Setup a Virtual Web Server using Linode or Digital Ocean"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4290468",
                "title": "PowerShell Functions Master Class"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3684468",
                "title": "Linux Command Line Terminal Basic for Beginners (In Hindi)"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3225779",
                "title": "Docker Course for Beginners"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4423690",
                "title": "Complete NFT Course (Beginner > 1000USD /Day Trading NFTs)"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3105814",
                "title": "Python-Introduction to Data Science and Machine learning A-Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4845712",
                "title": "Java Crash Course for Beginners 2022"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4359810",
                "title": "CSS, JavaScript,PHP And Python Programming All in One Course"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4233882",
                "title": "PSPO1 Practice Tests Scrum Product Owner certification-160Q"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4031642",
                "title": "PMI-ACP\u00ae- Agile Certified Project Management 200 Questions"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3495852",
                "title": "Python For Beginners Course In-Depth"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3062570",
                "title": "Building Android Widgets from scratch (Learn 8 Widgets)"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4363642",
                "title": "Cybersecurity- Security Operations Center (SOC) Analyst NOW!"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2205700",
                "title": "IP Addressing and Subnetting - Zero to Hero"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4121154",
                "title": "The Advanced SQL Course"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2879462",
                "title": "Public Speaking- A tactical approach"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3717522",
                "title": "Instagram Marketing 2021- Growth and Promotion on Instagram"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3612808",
                "title": "Master all the MS Excel Macros and the basics of Excel VBA"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4763230",
                "title": "Learn Python. Your First Computer Programming Class."
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3062508",
                "title": "Beginners guide to Android App Development (Step by Step)"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3518544",
                "title": "Learn Machine learning & AI (Including Hands-on 3 Projects)"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2411016",
                "title": "JavaScript, Bootstrap, & PHP - Certification for Beginners"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3542398",
                "title": "Build A Search Engine With Python- Computer Science & Python"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4286302",
                "title": "Python For Ethical Hacking"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "473160",
                "title": "Web Design for Web Developers- Build Beautiful Websites!"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "65330",
                "title": "Web Development By Doing- HTML / CSS From Scratch"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "173548",
                "title": "Build Your First Website in 1 Week with HTML5 and CSS3"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3156854",
                "title": "Cyber Security- The Ultimate Beginner's Handbook"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2760796",
                "title": "Data Science, Machine Learning, Data Analysis, Python & R"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "1639602",
                "title": "WordPress Web Design & Email Marketing"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4861820",
                "title": "Zero to Hero in Jest Unit and Integration Testing with React"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4551820",
                "title": "JavaScript And PHP Programming Complete Course"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3972018",
                "title": "HTML 5,Python,Flask Framework All In One Complete Course"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3047216",
                "title": "Python for beginners - Learn all the basics of python"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2617302",
                "title": "Apache Spark with Scala useful for Databricks Certification"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "2861796",
                "title": "Python And Django Framework For Beginners Complete Course"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "4425548",
                "title": "Learn MONGODB in 10 videos"
            }
        },
        {
            "course": {
                "id": "3014496",
                "title": "Python Hacking Course For Ethical Hackers"
            }
        }
    ],
    "status": true
}
```

**I Tried A Lot but i Cannot**

example: [This](https://flutterhope.com/beautiful-search-bar-flutter/)

I want to add Search bar like this and search in the list of widgets and display
Someone give me an idea to do it,
I dont know if it can be added or not
Thanks in advance.

I added required details. Maybe pubspec.yaml is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok you can use mapping though
final{}
and return data